# How to attach a thread to a specific USB port in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, usb

We have a system on which you can connect up to 4 USB handheld barcode scanner. Those scanners emulates keyboard wedge.

Now, I need to build an application in VB 2010 (framework 4.0) to manage those scanners. Each scanner must be managed independently. Is it possible to, say, create a thread once a scanner is connected and listen for this specific USB port? How can I do this?

thanks for your time and help

Comment: well, I haven't done anything yet, beside looking all over the web for a way to do it, because I have no idea how, I've never worked dealt with USB port before

Comment: There are dozens of questions here (including several in the **Related** list to the immediate right of this question) that discuss getting input from USB devices, including keyboard wedge type barcode scanners. Start with those and an investigation of the WinAPI `AttachThreadInput` function (and read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/19/10426841.aspx) as well), and then you can ask a more specific (meaning *less broad*) question here. Your best bet is to use scanners that can support serial mode as well as keyboard mode, and access them as serial (COM) ports.

Comment: ok, I'll follow your advice, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If the scanners are identical, the problem will be knowing which scanner is on which port. Unfortunately, Windows can sometimes change the COM port being emulated even if you don't disconnect/reconnect.